# Access publish function's this, inside a function called by publish - Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a publish method which calls another method inside it, like this:

```js
Meteor.publish("myList", function() {
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
  // i want to access the publish methods *this* here
}
```

I have a usecase that i should access the Meteor.publish `this` inside myFunction method without passing any parameter.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Don't know exactly,how about setting session variable and getting the results?

Comment: @sasikanth `Meteor.publish` is a server-side feature, while `Session` is a client-side feature.

Comment: I understand this doesn't answer your question, but I've generally preferred to do the following:

    var publication = this;
    myFunction(publication, otherArg0, otherArg1);

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for one of the following standard JavaScript features:

- [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Since you are not passing any parameters to the function, either will work fine, but `call()` is probably the best choice.

These allow you to call a function, while setting the value of `this` inside the function to whatever value you want. So for your case, it might look something like this:

```js
Meteor.publish("myList", function() {
  // sends the current function's `this` value to the other function, so the
  // other function can access it as its own `this`
  myFunction.call(this);
});

function myFunction() {
  // the value of `this` will be whatever you passed to the `call()` method
  console.log(this);
}
```

Note that by default, when you call a function on its own (without the dot operator, `call()`, `apply()`, or using the other special method `bind()`), a function's `this` value will be the global object (a special object called `global` on the server, or the special `window` object on the browser). If you are using ES5 strict mode (you would know if you are), the value of `this` by default will be `null`.

Comment: I'm looking without passing parameter. Somethig like "super.this" or like that. The caller methods this

Comment: There's no way to do that. Could you expand on why you can't pass a parameter? Using `call(this)` isn't passing a parameter, just setting the `this` value at runtime. As you can see in my code example, the other function has no parameters.

Comment: @shamohd This question sounds like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you give more details on what you're actually trying to do, it would be much easier to solve your problem. I can't think of a situation where your proposed solution would be necessary; I guarantee there's a better way to do it. In fact, if your solution were a possible feature of the language, it would likely manifest in some security and performance issues.